# Woocommerce Dashboard filter Product List by stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add 2 custom filters to dashboard products list. The filters are "Out of Stock" and "In Stock". How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/94630/12615). You should be able to adapt it. And if it doesn't work, make an on-topic Question with your attempt ([ask]) in the correct site.

Comment: I found a similar solution to this link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo/45447#45447